# Mouse freezes when virus scanning or installing software

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, intel-core-i5

I have a problem with my mouse freezing. I use Windows 8.1 on a Toshiba PC with 4GB RAM/i5 CPU.

When I install software (like Visual Basic) or start a virus scan, my mouse lags for eight seconds to two minutes, and the Synaptics Pointing device does not work (like pinch to zoom et cetera).

I think the problem is from my HDD, but I don't know how to troubleshoot it. The PC is still new. I already updated all drivers (including the drivers for my mouse/HDD), but nothing changed.

Comment: Does your mouse freezes that moment or it moves but lags a lot? You can try to unplug the mouse and then re-plug it in. This happens when the explorer.exe process is eating much of the memory of your RAM or when the HDD is R/W very quickly. Also when your anticirus scans your computer there is a lot of R/W on your HDD.

Comment: Please don't delete and re-post questions. This is considered abusive and may lead to your account being blocked from asking further questions.

Comment: @Hunter : no the mouse freezes I can't move it , I'm speaking about touchpad

Comment: @user3080016 Can you try to terminate your explorer.exe process or the antivirus when you're scanning. For this press (CTRL+Shift+Esc) to open task manager and find the process by going into the detials tab and the process tree.

Comment: I found explorer.exe I make end task or what?

Comment: no one can help ? :(

Comment: Sorry didn't saw it earlier, you should Restart it. It will work automatically after some seconds.